# Send array from Python to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, tcp

I am working on a school project where I have to capture the screen with Python, and then send the information of the screen to Matlab in order to process and test that with some algorithms in Simulink. However, I don-t know how should I send the information from Python to Matlab, I have been trying to use TCP/IP using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3           # This is server.py file
import socket    
import numpy as np        
import pickle     
import struct                        

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
        socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

                         
host='localhost'
port = 50001                                         

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

a=np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ])


# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)
                                     
try:
  while True:
  # establish a connection
  clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

  print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
  #/---------------------
  msg=pickle.dumps(a)
  clientsocket.send(msg)
  #--------------------------
  #msg=str(5)
 
 #clientsocket.close()
```

When I try to receive the data from another Python instance, it works properly but the problem comes when I try to read the data from Matlab, it does not work as intended. Using the following code in Matlab

```
t=tcpip('localhost',50001,'NetworkRole','client')
fopen(t)
bytes = fread(t, [1, t.BytesAvailable])
```

I get to read the data but it shows as an array of 1x229 doubles. How can I translate that into the array that was intented to transmit?

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't use `pickle`, MATLAB will not be able to understand that binary format. Just send the data in the array.

Comment: Is there a way to send multiple arrays continuously. For instance, when the first array is transmitted, the second one is sent and read from Matlab